# PHP class extends not working why and is this how to correctly extend a class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, extend

Hi so I'm trying to understand how inherteince works in PHP using object oriented programming. The main class is Computer, the class that is inheriting is Mouse. I'm extedning the Computer class with the mouse class. I use __construct in each class, when I istinate the class I use the pc type first and if it has mouse after. For some reason computer returns null? why is this?

```
class Computer {
    protected $type = 'null';

    public function __construct($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
    public function computertype() {
        $this->type = strtoupper($this->type);
        return $this->type;
    }

}

class Mouse extends Computer {
    protected $hasmouse = 'null';
    public function __construct($hasmouse){
         $this->hasmouse = $hasmouse;

    }
    public function computermouse() {
         if($this->hasmouse == 'Y') {
             return 'This Computer has a mouse';
         }
    }

}

$pc = new Computer('PC', 'Y');
echo $pc->computertype;
echo $pc->computermouse;
```

Comment: not a directly related answer, but it would make more sense if your computer object had a mouse property, which was an object of type mouse

Comment: @Erik I this Comment Helped me out the most, made me rethink the construction of the parent class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work quite like that. If you create a `new Computer` you get just that. You want to create a `new Mouse()` which is of the type computer (although that seems like strange inheretance to me).

The parent object (computer) has no idea that it has a child (mouse). This is because a parent class can have multiple children.

Generally you'd have something like a apple extending computer, or dell extending computer then you'd have

```
$a = new apple();
$b = new dell();
```

and they'd both have the methods available that are defined in computer, plus their own methods.

Additionally when you override a method like `__construct` you have to explicitly call the parent constructor (or method) if you want it to execute, for example:

```
class computer {
   function __construct() { do stuff }
}

class apple extends computer {
   function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

Only the method of the class you instantiated gets executed. If it cant find the method in the child class it then looks up the chain for a method. ie. if the `computer` class has 'movemouse' and your child class doesn't it would execute the `movemouse` class in the parent.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how inheritance works.

Inheritance (aka `extend`) allows you to extend child classes based on the properties and methods of their parent class.

Consider the following for example:

```
class Peripheral {
  private $connectionType;
  private $isConnected = false;

  function __construct($connectionType) {
    $this->connectionType = $connectionType;
  }

  function getConnectionType() {
    return $this->connectionType;
  }

  function connect() {
    $this->isConnected = true;
  }

  function disconnect() {
    $this->isConnected = false;
  } 

  function isConnected() {
    return $this->isConnected;
  }
}
```

You may now extend the `Peripheral` class because a `Mouse` is a Peripheral.

```
class Mouse extends Peripheral {
  private $numOfButtons;

  function __construct($connectionType, $numberOfButtons) {
    parent::__construct($connectionType);
    $this->numOfButtons = $numOfButtons;
  }

  function getNumOfButtons() {
    return $this->numOfButtons;
  }

  function leftClick() {
    if($this->isConnected())
      echo "Click!";
  }

  function rightClick() {
    if($this->isConnected())
      echo "RightClick!";
  }
}
```

Now, because `Mouse` is a subclass of `Peripheral`, all the methods defined in `Peripheral` are accessible in `Mouse`, but not the other way around...

So while I can do this:

```
$mouse = new Mouse('USB', 2);
echo $mouse->getConnectionType(); // USB
$mouse->connect();
$mouse->leftClick();
```

I cannot do the following:

```
$perip = new Peripheral('USB');
echo $perip->getConnectionType(); // USB
$perip->connect();
$perip->leftClick(); // ERROR: leftClick not defined.
```

Comment: can you please show me how I would create and instance of those classes?

Comment: Great write up, crystal clear, and should be upvoted to the top!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

$pc = new Computer('PC', 'Y');

you want

$mouse = new Mouse('PC', 'Y');

Currently you have it so Mouse extends Computer.

Comment: ok I've reversed them but computer is still returning null but in uppercase due to strtoupper then 'PCTYPE' next to it?

Comment: my answer addresses why you have a null value. both constructors aren't running.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with inheritance is the "is-a" concept. In your example code, a Mouse is a Computer. So that means a Mouse can do everything a computer can, potentially plus some functionality or in a different way.  You seem to be wanting a "has-a" relationship which isn't usually inheritance, but composition. A computer has a mouse, therefore the constructor of computer could take a Mouse or has a setter for the Mouse object.

Comment: @Myles,  agreed.  I was going to elaborate further but @Erik summed it up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Your current Mouse constructor will only accept one value. If you want Mouse to accept both $type and $hasmouse, then you need to accept two values.

```
class Mouse extends Computer {
    protected $hasmouse = 'null';
    public function __construct($type, $hasmouse) {
        parent::__construct($type);
        $this->hasmouse = $hasmouse;
    }
    public function computermouse() {
         if($this->hasmouse == 'Y') {
             return 'This Computer has a mouse';
         }
    }
}

$pc = new Mouse('PC', 'Y');
```

I would also suggest using boolean (true/false) instead of 'Y'

Comment: Why would you suggest using Boolean variables?

Comment: Think of it this way. Statement: It has a mouse? True/False. This also makes it easier to use in conditionals: `if($this->hasmouse)`. And finally, because its a standard convention. Someday someone will maintain your software other then you -- if you do things like "Y" and "N" for true/false, hope they don't know where you live.